# Django Rest test not giving XML as response but json

Tags: python, json, xml, django, django-rest-framework

This is my view

```
from rest_framework_xml.renderers import XMLRenderer

@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'POST'])
@renderer_classes((XMLRenderer,))
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def users(request, id, format=None):
    serializer = MySerializer(model,  context={'request': request})
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

If i visit the URL by browser then i get XML as response in chrome as desired.

But in my tests

```
url = reverse('user-detail', kwargs={
    'id': 10,
})
response = self.client.get(url)
result = response.data
```

I get the result as dictionary . I mean the result which i get before passing to XMLRender.

I don't know if thats the desired behaviour but how can test the xml response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.data` property of the [Response](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/#attributes) holds the unrendered content. You want to access `.content` to see your rendered XML.